# How to configure Ganache as network on hardhat-config

Tags: ganache, hardhat

I'm having a hard time trying to configure **Ganache** as a network on `Hardhat`.

```sol
networks: {
  ganache: {
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:7545",
    chainId: "7777",
    accounts: [
      `0x4f3edf983ac636a65a842ce7c78d9aa706d3b113bce9c46f30d7d21715b23b1d`,
      `0xe485d098507f54e7733a205420dfddbe58db035fa577fc294ebd14db90767a52`,
    ],
  },
},
```

I got this **error message**:

```zsh
Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

  * Invalid value {"url":"http://127.0.0.1:7545","chainId":"7777","accounts":["0x4f3edf983ac636a65a842ce7c78d9aa706d3b113bce9c46f30d7d21715b23b1d","0xe485d098507f54e7733a205420dfddbe58db035fa577fc294ebd14db90767a52"]} for HardhatConfig.networks.ganache - Expected a value of type HttpNetworkConfig.
```

> Is it possible to do this configuration and use Ganache as a local network?

Comment: Try using `"` instead of `

Answer (score 3):

I realized that to use Ganache as my local blockchain with Hardhat,I just have to start Ganache with chainId expected by Hardhat, 31337, and I don't have to do anything in the `networks` section of hardhat-config.js:

```
ganache -p 8545 --chain.chainId 31337
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are correct that it seems to need a chainId of 1337 to work properly (changing the value of `chainId` will cause an error, albeit one different from the one you got) the issue you're seeing there is that you have defined the value of `chainId` as a `string` and not a `number`.

I am using Ganache AppImage, so [I am unable to change the `chainId`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/90385/the-endpoint-returned-a-different-chain-id-0x539-ganache) as you show above, but you could try your example with `7777` (without the quotes) if you use the CLI and can set a different chain ID

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to add chain id
I have run ganach on my local machine
Below is the hardhat configuration file

```
    module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 1337,
    },
    ganache: {
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:7000",
      accounts: [
        `7bc522e9ba27f118ad4157771bec290f59ffffe45ee66bb81f137043150bd2`,
      ],
    }

  },
  paths: {
    artifacts: "./src/artifacts",
  }
};
```

After these run following command and it will deploy contract on ganache network

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network ganache
```